# why is this butterworth filter presenting different results in R and Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, filter, butterworth

I'm trying to use a 20Hz low pass filter on data in R, but when I use the filtfilt function, the plot is different from the matlab.

I'm using the following code in R:

```
fc<-20
fs<-100
Wn<-pi*fc/(2*fs)
testar<- butter(5, Wn, type="low")
L2<- signal::filtfilt(testar,Tabela$posicao)
plot(Tabela$tempo, L2, type = "l", col="red")
```

The matlab code is:

```
fc=20;
fs=100;
Wn=pi*fc/(2*fs);
[b,a] = butter(5,Wn,'low');
posfilt= filtfilt(b,a,Tabela.posicao);
```

The plot in matlab is:

[image: matlab plot]

The R one:

[image: R plot]

why the R one is presenting those variation in the begin and in the end of the graph?

Data can be produced as follows:

```
Tabela <- data.table::fread("
tempo   posicao
0   870.22
1   870.27
2   870.33
3   870.39
4   870.46
5   870.52
6   870.57
7   870.61
8   870.63
9   870.65
10  870.66
11  870.68
12  870.7
13  870.73
14  870.76
15  870.79
16  870.81
17  870.82
18  870.83
19  870.83
20  870.83
21  870.84
22  870.85
23  870.85
24  870.85
25  870.83
26  870.79
27  870.74
28  870.69
29  870.63
30  870.59
31  870.57
32  870.56
33  870.55
34  870.53
35  870.51
36  870.46
37  870.42
38  870.37
39  870.33
40  870.31
41  870.3
42  870.3
43  870.31
44  870.31
45  870.31
46  870.33
47  870.36
48  870.42
49  870.52
50  870.64
51  870.77
52  870.87
53  870.92
54  870.91
55  870.82
56  870.68
57  870.51
58  870.37
59  870.27
60  870.25
61  870.29
62  870.38
63  870.5
64  870.61
65  870.69
66  870.74
67  870.76
68  870.76
69  870.75
70  870.74
71  870.74
72  870.76
73  870.78
74  870.81
75  870.86
76  870.93
77  871.02
78  871.12
79  871.23
80  871.33
81  871.42
82  871.47
83  871.5
84  871.52
85  871.52
86  871.54
87  871.57
88  871.62
89  871.67
90  871.71
91  871.73
92  871.72
93  871.68
94  871.64
95  871.59
96  871.58
97  871.59
98  871.62
99  871.66
100 871.7
101 871.7
102 871.69
103 871.65
104 871.6
105 871.56
106 871.54
107 871.52
108 871.52
109 871.5
110 871.48
111 871.43
112 871.38
113 871.31
114 871.24
115 871.17
116 871.12
117 871.07
118 871.02
119 870.99
120 870.97
121 870.97
122 870.98
123 871.00
124 871.02
125 871.04
126 871.04
127 871.02
128 870.97
129 870.91
130 870.84
131 870.78
132 870.74
133 870.72
134 870.72
135 870.72
136 870.72
137 870.71
138 870.69
139 870.68
140 870.69
141 870.72
142 870.77
143 870.84
144 870.92
145 871.01
146 871.1
147 871.19
148 871.28
149 871.36
150 871.43
151 871.49
152 871.55
153 871.6
154 871.67
155 871.74
156 871.84
157 871.95
158 872.07
159 872.2
160 872.31
161 872.42
162 872.51
163 872.59
164 872.66
165 872.75
166 872.86
167 873.02
168 873.22
169 873.48
170 873.8
171 874.16
172 874.55
173 874.99
174 875.49
175 876.06
176 876.72
177 877.48
178 878.36
179 879.33
180 880.41
181 881.59
182 882.87
183 884.24
184 885.71
185 887.29
186 888.96
187 890.73
188 892.61
189 894.57
190 896.63
191 898.77
192 900.99
193 903.28
194 905.63
195 908.02
196 910.44
197 912.88
198 915.33
199 917.79
200 920.25
201 922.71
202 925.15
203 927.57
204 929.96
205 932.3
206 934.59
207 936.82
208 938.99
209 941.09
210 943.14
211 945.12
212 947.05
213 948.89
214 950.62
215 952.2
216 953.62
217 954.86
218 955.94
219 956.86
220 957.65
221 958.33
222 958.9
223 959.4
224 959.83
225 960.2
226 960.53
227 960.82
228 961.09
229 961.35
230 961.58
231 961.81
232 962.02
233 962.23
234 962.45
235 962.7
236 962.98
237 963.32
238 963.7
239 964.13
240 964.6
241 965.09
242 965.59
243 966.09
244 966.59
245 967.1
246 967.62
247 968.15
248 968.69
249 969.25
250 969.81
251 970.36
252 970.89
253 971.4
254 971.89
255 972.33
256 972.73
257 973.08
258 973.38
259 973.63
260 973.85
261 974.05
262 974.25
263 974.44
264 974.63
265 974.8
266 974.96
267 975.1
268 975.24
269 975.37
270 975.5
271 975.64
272 975.8
273 975.96
274 976.13
275 976.32
276 976.52
277 976.74
278 976.97
279 977.21
280 977.44
281 977.66
282 977.84
283 977.97
284 978.05
285 978.06
286 978.01
287 977.9
288 977.74
289 977.53
290 977.28
291 976.99
292 976.67
293 976.34
294 976.01
295 975.68
296 975.35
297 975.02
298 974.68
299 974.31
300 973.91
301 973.48
302 973.04
303 972.58
304 972.14
305 971.71
306 971.32
307 970.97
308 970.67
309 970.41
310 970.2
311 970.02
312 969.89
313 969.78
314 969.72
315 969.68
316 969.67
317 969.67
318 969.67
319 969.67
320 969.67
321 969.68
322 969.69
323 969.73
324 969.79
325 969.88
326 969.98
327 970.08
328 970.17
329 970.24
330 970.28
331 970.29
332 970.27
333 970.22
334 970.15
335 970.07
336 969.98
337 969.89
338 969.81
339 969.74
340 969.68
341 969.63
342 969.6
343 969.57
344 969.56
345 969.55
346 969.57
347 969.6
348 969.65
349 969.73
350 969.81
351 969.89
352 969.96
353 970.01
354 970.05
355 970.06
356 970.07
357 970.08
358 970.09
359 970.09
360 970.09
361 970.08
362 970.06
363 970.04
364 970.00
365 969.96
366 969.94
367 969.93
368 969.95
369 970.00
370 970.08
371 970.17
372 970.27
373 970.35
374 970.42
375 970.48
376 970.53
377 970.58
378 970.64
379 970.73
380 970.85
381 970.98
382 971.14
383 971.3
384 971.45
385 971.58
386 971.69
387 971.76
388 971.79
389 971.8
390 971.78
391 971.75
392 971.71
393 971.66
394 971.61
395 971.55
396 971.48
397 971.39
398 971.3
399 971.2
400 971.1
401 971.00
402 970.9
403 970.82
404 970.76
405 970.73
406 970.72
407 970.73
408 970.77
409 970.83
410 970.9
411 970.98
412 971.06
413 971.16
414 971.27
415 971.4
416 971.53
417 971.67
418 971.81
419 971.94
420 972.06
421 972.17
422 972.25
423 972.33
424 972.38
425 972.42
426 972.45
427 972.45
428 972.44
429 972.42
430 972.38
431 972.34
432 972.29
433 972.24
434 972.2
435 972.16
436 972.12
437 972.1
438 972.08
439 972.07
440 972.07
441 972.07
442 972.07
443 972.08
444 972.09
445 972.12
446 972.18
447 972.26
448 972.37
449 972.49
450 972.61
451 972.7
452 972.78
453 972.82
454 972.83
455 972.82
456 972.79
457 972.76
458 972.71
459 972.65
460 972.57
461 972.49
462 972.39
463 972.29
464 972.19
465 972.11
466 972.07
467 972.05
468 972.07
469 972.1
470 972.14
471 972.17
472 972.19
473 972.2
474 972.21
475 972.22
476 972.25
477 972.29
478 972.36
479 972.44
480 972.52
481 972.61
482 972.68
483 972.74
484 972.78
485 972.81
486 972.83
487 972.85
488 972.86
489 972.88
490 972.9
491 972.92
492 972.95
493 972.97
494 972.99
495 973.00
496 972.99
497 972.97
498 972.93
499 972.88
500 972.83
501 972.78
502 972.73
503 972.69
504 972.66
505 972.64
506 972.64
507 972.66
508 972.7
509 972.76
510 972.83
511 972.92
512 973.02
513 973.13
514 973.25
515 973.39
516 973.56
517 973.74
518 973.94
519 974.14
520 974.34
521 974.52
522 974.68
523 974.82
524 974.94
525 975.06
526 975.18
527 975.3
528 975.43
529 975.58
530 975.73
531 975.88
532 976.02
533 976.15
534 976.27
535 976.4
536 976.53
537 976.67
538 976.82
539 976.99
540 977.17
541 977.35
542 977.53
543 977.71
544 977.88
545 978.03
546 978.18
547 978.31
548 978.44
549 978.55
550 978.63
551 978.69
552 978.72
553 978.73
554 978.73
555 978.72
556 978.71
557 978.69
558 978.67
559 978.62
560 978.54
561 978.41
562 978.22
563 977.96
564 977.62
565 977.19
566 976.67
567 976.05
568 975.32
569 974.47
570 973.48
571 972.34
572 971.03
573 969.52
574 967.79
575 965.83
576 963.64
577 961.2
578 958.52
579 955.62
580 952.5
581 949.16
582 945.6
583 941.83
584 937.85
585 933.68
586 929.33
587 924.8
588 920.12
589 915.3
590 910.35
591 905.29
592 900.13
593 894.88
594 889.56
595 884.18
596 878.76
597 873.31
598 867.84
599 862.37
600 856.93
601 851.52
602 846.16
603 840.86
604 835.64
605 830.48
606 825.41
607 820.4
608 815.46
609 810.57
610 805.74
611 800.96
612 796.25
613 791.59
614 786.99
615 782.46
616 777.99
617 773.57
618 769.2
619 764.89
620 760.64
621 756.45
622 752.32
623 748.25
624 744.24
625 740.31
626 736.46
627 732.69
628 729.03
629 725.5
630 722.1
631 718.83
632 715.7
633 712.68
634 709.77
635 706.96
636 704.25
637 701.63
638 699.13
639 696.75
640 694.49
641 692.36
642 690.34
643 688.42
644 686.6
645 684.85
646 683.17
647 681.56
648 680.01
649 678.52
650 677.1
651 675.75
652 674.49
653 673.3
654 672.19
655 671.15
656 670.16
657 669.22
658 668.33
659 667.5
660 666.74
661 666.05
662 665.42
663 664.85
664 664.32
665 663.82
666 663.35
667 662.93
668 662.57
669 662.27
670 662.05
671 661.89
672 661.77
673 661.69
674 661.62
675 661.56
676 661.5
677 661.44
678 661.38
679 661.34
680 661.29
681 661.25
682 661.2
683 661.13
684 661.05
685 660.95
686 660.83
687 660.7
688 660.57
689 660.43
690 660.28
691 660.13
692 659.96
693 659.78
694 659.6
695 659.43
696 659.29
697 659.2
698 659.16
699 659.19
700 659.28
701 659.43
702 659.65
703 659.96
704 660.37
705 660.9
706 661.54
707 662.31
708 663.19
709 664.2
710 665.33
711 666.58
712 667.94
713 669.43
714 671.02
715 672.73
716 674.55
717 676.46
718 678.46
719 680.55
720 682.73
721 685.00
722 687.36
723 689.81
724 692.34
725 694.92
726 697.54
727 700.15
728 702.73
729 705.28
730 707.79
731 710.27
732 712.76
733 715.26
734 717.8
735 720.38
736 722.98
737 725.6
738 728.21
739 730.81
740 733.39
741 735.96
742 738.5
743 741.02
744 743.52
745 746.00
746 748.45
747 750.87
748 753.25
749 755.58
750 757.87
751 760.12
752 762.34
753 764.53
754 766.71
755 768.86
756 770.99
757 773.09
758 775.16
759 777.2
760 779.23
761 781.24
762 783.25
763 785.26
764 787.28
765 789.3
766 791.31
767 793.33
768 795.34
769 797.35
770 799.35
771 801.34
772 803.33
773 805.31
774 807.29
775 809.26
776 811.21
777 813.16
778 815.09
779 817.03
780 818.96
781 820.91
782 822.88
783 824.85
784 826.82
785 828.78
786 830.73
787 832.67
788 834.59
789 836.5
790 838.41
791 840.33
792 842.27
793 844.23
794 846.2
795 848.18
796 850.15
797 852.1
798 854.02
799 855.93
800 857.84
801 859.76
802 861.71
803 863.69
804 865.69
805 867.72
806 869.75
807 871.79
808 873.83
809 875.88
810 877.94
811 880.02
812 882.12
813 884.25
814 886.41
815 888.59
816 890.78
817 892.97
818 895.18
819 897.39
820 899.61
821 901.85
822 904.11
823 906.38
824 908.67
825 910.97
826 913.29
827 915.61
828 917.94
829 920.28
830 922.63
831 925.00
832 927.38
833 929.79
834 932.22
835 934.68
836 937.17
837 939.67
838 942.17
839 944.67
840 947.15
841 949.62
842 952.08
843 954.51
844 956.94
845 959.36
846 961.75
847 964.12
848 966.45
849 968.73
850 970.94
851 973.07
852 975.12
853 977.08
854 978.94
855 980.7
856 982.34
857 983.86
858 985.26
859 986.52
860 987.65
861 988.64
862 989.49
863 990.2
864 990.76
865 991.16
866 991.42
867 991.52
868 991.48
869 991.3
870 991.01
871 990.63
872 990.18
873 989.67
874 989.13
875 988.56
876 987.98
877 987.39
878 986.79
879 986.2
880 985.61
881 985.04
882 984.52
883 984.05
884 983.65
885 983.32
886 983.07
887 982.88
888 982.74
889 982.64
890 982.55
891 982.47
892 982.38
893 982.28
894 982.15
895 981.98
896 981.78
897 981.54
898 981.26
899 980.94
900 980.61
901 980.28
902 979.94
903 979.61
904 979.29
905 978.98
906 978.68
907 978.39
908 978.11
909 977.85
910 977.6
911 977.37
912 977.16
913 976.94
914 976.72
915 976.5
916 976.27
917 976.06
918 975.85
919 975.67
920 975.5
921 975.36
922 975.22
923 975.08
924 974.93
925 974.76
926 974.57
927 974.35
928 974.1
929 973.85
930 973.6
931 973.36
932 973.13
933 972.93
934 972.74
935 972.55
936 972.37
937 972.19
938 972.00
939 971.8
940 971.6
941 971.39
942 971.18
943 970.97
944 970.76
945 970.56
946 970.37
947 970.19
948 970.02
949 969.86
950 969.72
951 969.6
952 969.5
953 969.42
954 969.36
955 969.33
956 969.29
957 969.27
958 969.23
959 969.19
960 969.14
961 969.09
962 969.04
963 968.99
964 968.94
965 968.88
966 968.82
967 968.74
968 968.64
969 968.54
970 968.42
971 968.3
972 968.19
973 968.08
974 967.98
975 967.86
976 967.74
977 967.59
978 967.42
979 967.24
980 967.04
981 966.85
982 966.67
983 966.5
984 966.35
985 966.2
986 966.06
987 965.92
988 965.77
989 965.61
990 965.44
991 965.25
992 965.05
993 964.82
994 964.58
995 964.32
996 964.05
997 963.78
998 963.52
999 963.28
1000    963.06
1001    962.85
1002    962.65
1003    962.44
1004    962.18
1005    961.87
1006    961.49
1007    961.03
1008    960.49
1009    959.91
1010    959.32
1011    958.75
1012    958.23
1013    957.77
1014    957.33
1015    956.9
1016    956.43
1017    955.87
1018    955.19
1019    954.37
1020    953.43
1021    952.39
1022    951.28
1023    950.13
1024    948.96
1025    947.74
1026    946.48
1027    945.15
1028    943.74
1029    942.26
1030    940.72
1031    939.11
1032    937.45
1033    935.74
1034    933.95
1035    932.07
1036    930.11
1037    928.06
1038    925.97
1039    923.92
1040    921.98
1041    920.24
1042    918.75
1043    917.51
1044    916.51
1045    915.7
1046    915.04
1047    914.51
1048    914.1
1049    913.76
1050    913.44
1051    913.05
1052    912.52
1053    911.79
1054    910.86
1055    909.74
1056    908.49
1057    907.19
1058    905.91
1059    904.73
1060    903.71
1061    902.89
1062    902.28
1063    901.88
1064    901.66
1065    901.59
1066    901.65
1067    901.81
1068    902.03
1069    902.3
1070    902.56
1071    902.79
1072    902.96
1073    903.06
1074    903.09
1075    903.06
1076    902.97
1077    902.85
1078    902.7
1079    902.53
1080    902.36
1081    902.21
1082    902.07
1083    901.95
1084    901.83
1085    901.67
1086    901.46
1087    901.17
1088    900.77
1089    900.26
1090    899.61
1091    898.81
1092    897.85
1093    896.73
1094    895.47
1095    894.12
1096    892.74
1097    891.4
1098    890.16
1099    889.04
1100    888.02
1101    887.1
1102    886.26
1103    885.5
1104    884.81
1105    884.15
1106    883.45
1107    882.61
1108    881.56
1109    880.29
1110    878.88
1111    877.44
1112    876.11
1113    875.01
1114    874.2
1115    873.65
1116    873.28
1117    872.99
1118    872.69
1119    872.36
1120    872.02
1121    871.74
1122    871.56
1123    871.5
1124    871.53
1125    871.6
1126    871.62
1127    871.58
1128    871.45
1129    871.26
1130    871.06
1131    870.9
1132    870.81
1133    870.82
1134    870.92
1135    871.06
1136    871.21
1137    871.32
1138    871.36
1139    871.33
1140    871.24
1141    871.14
1142    871.08
1143    871.08
1144    871.15
1145    871.28
1146    871.43
1147    871.56
1148    871.62
1149    871.6
1150    871.51
1151    871.37
1152    871.2
1153    871.04
1154    870.89
1155    870.77
1156    870.66
1157    870.55
1158    870.44
1159    870.32
1160    870.22
1161    870.13
1162    870.08
1163    870.06
1164    870.07
1165    870.09
1166    870.12
1167    870.14
1168    870.13
1169    870.11
1170    870.08
1171    870.05
1172    870.03
1173    870.03
1174    870.04
1175    870.04
1176    870.03
1177    869.99
1178    869.93
1179    869.87
1180    869.83
1181    869.81
1182    869.83
1183    869.88
1184    869.94
1185    870.00
1186    870.03
1187    870.03
1188    870.02
1189    870.00
1190    870.00
1191    870.00
1192    870.03
1193    870.06
1194    870.1
1195    870.14
1196    870.17
1197    870.2
1198    870.24
1199    870.28
1200    870.33
1201    870.37
1202    870.39
1203    870.39
1204    870.36
1205    870.31
1206    870.24
1207    870.18
1208    870.13
1209    870.09
1210    870.05
1211    870.01
1212    869.95
1213    869.88
1214    869.81
1215    869.75
1216    869.72
1217    869.73
1218    869.77
1219    869.85
1220    869.93
1221    870.01
1222    870.06
1223    870.1
1224    870.11
1225    870.11
1226    870.11
1227    870.11
1228    870.11
1229    870.12
1230    870.14
1231    870.16")
```

Comment: Can you clarify what Tabela$posicao or Tabela.posicao is? I could not reproduce your problem because its undefined in both MATLAB and R

Comment: I user an Excel data called Tabela, and posicao is the column I had to filter

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-3kwgVcnW61HSVlogz6FHNdTCW7YG7um

Answer (score 4):

I have hunch that the difference is in how each version handles end-effect transients.

Your signal has a large DC-offset (`~875`). If you think of the signal as being zero `0` before and after the recording. The jump at the start of the signal gets processed by the filter and is seen as an artifact or end-effect. These end-effects are what you see in the R version of the filtered signal.

From the R documentation from `filtfilt` this version is old and likely doesn't minimize the end transients ([R 'filtfilt' docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/signal/versions/0.7-6/topics/filtfilt)). On the other hand the MATLAB version of `filtfilt` does; Quoting from the MATLAB documentation:

"[filtfilt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) minimizes start-up and ending transients by matching initial conditions. Do not use 'filtfilt' with differentiator and Hilbert FIR filters, because the operation of these filters depends heavily on their phase response." [FILTFILT Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Azim, the default implementation of `signal::filtfilt()` does not include any steps to remove end-effect transients. However, a very simple function that pads the series with a reversed values before/after and then subsets the result to the original range of interest can solve this problem.

```
EndEffect <- function(filt,x) {
  signal::filtfilt(filt,c(rev(x),x,rev(x)))[(length(x) + 1):(2 * length(x))]
}


L2<- EndEffect(testar,Tabela$posicao)
plot(Tabela$tempo, L2, type = "l", col="red")
```

[image]