# Butterworth filter R and Octave results do not match with the seemingly same algorithm

Tags: r, filtering, signal-processing, octave

I am new to signal processing. I am using the Signal package and trying to translate an Octave code snippet to R. The original snippet is from a tutorial pdf that I link below.

Everything seems to work fine until the application of the last function. I am probably making a silly mistake, but I could not get to the bottom of this. Here is what I have.

The Octave code is the following:

```
pkg load signal
x=load ('wcr0301164a.emg');
fs =  10000;
fnyq = fs/2;
y  = abs(x-mean(x));
fco=20;
[b,a]=butter(2,fco*1.25/fnyq);
z=filtfilt(b,a,y);
```

And, my R code is as follows:

```
library(signal)

x <- read.csv('~/Dropbox/FFT/wcr0301164a.emg',header=F)
x <- x[[1]]
y <- abs(x-mean(x))

fs <- 10000
fnyq <- fs/2
fco <- 20
butter <- butter(2,fco*1.25/fnyq)
z <- filtfilt(butter,y)
```

When I compare the z vectors, with the former I get

```
0.7478, 0.7450, 0.7422, 0.7395,  0.7367...
```

whereas with the latter I get

```
0.2562217 0.2589562 0.2616876 0.2644153 0.2671385,...
```

All the values, including the butter coefficients a and b, match until the last step.  Can anyone tell where I am messing up?

I took the data from the following URLhttps://www1.udel.edu/biology/rosewc/kaap686/reserve/labview/wcr0301164a.emg

The tutorial is herehttps://www1.udel.edu/biology/rosewc/kaap686/notes/EMG%20analysis.pdf.

Comment: Update: I found another post that maybe related.  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950001/why-is-this-butterworth-filter-presenting-different-results-in-r-and-matlab>